# PHP - Mysql put a $row[] in a variable cut the text after the first space

Tags: php, mysqli

new in PHP my question can be very easy for you :)

example of the issue:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) { 
$res_hed = $mysqli->query("select VAT FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE id=$_GET[edit]");

for ($row_no = $res_hed->num_rows - 1; $row_no >= 0; $row_no--) {
$VAT = $row['VAT'];
                    }
echo "
<form class='col-md-3' method='GET'>
<h3>Edit VAT</h3>
<div class='form-group'>
<label>VAT</label>
<input class='form-control' type='text' name='VAT' value=$VAT>
</div>
?>      
}
```

Data in table for field VAT = 'GB1122 155 4555'
When the value is set in the variable $VAT i get only  'GB1122'

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I'll bet @NigelRen's right.  If you look at the source of your output HTML, you'll probably see `... value=GB1122 155 4555>` which would only output GB1122.  If you add the quotes, the problem would go away.

Comment: Where do you populate the variable $row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value attribute should be in quotes

```
<input class='form-control' type='text' name='VAT' value='$VAT'>
```

You may also be missing the end " off the text...

```
</div>";
```

Comment: How can it solve the issue where part of the data is missing?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed see the comment from JBH - without quotes it is most likely `value=GB1122 155 4555>` which will mean it will treat 155 and 4555 as other attributes.

Comment: But it should be in the view html on the browser. Did you see the for loop just iterates? Did you think where the $row is defined or populated. I just wonder why people voting this answer blindly

Comment: @RinsadAhmed, I can see that, but also they say *$VAT i get only 'GB1122'*, which means the data may be populated in code that isn't shown.  Please feel free to post an answer if you wish.

Comment: Does it make any sense? How can the above code work? You won't question it or correct it? I can see you are a vetaran

Comment: @RinsadAhmed, why are you questioning me on what I'm doing/not doing?  If you have issues with OP's code then please address it to them and provide an answer if you want to.

Comment: value attribute should be in quotes  did the job thanks.